# UITableView scroll on top of cell (or how to keep a cell static)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Recently I've been trying to implement the following behavior in my own app:

[image]

As you see, when you scroll the table view up, the first cell **remains at its place** while others scroll up and overlap it.

Have been searching for a solution for a couple of days and so far I've only found solutions that involve using headers. But the issue is that headers "stick" to the top whereas I need first cell to stay static.

Also had an idea about using a top constraint to keep the cell at place but don't quite understand how to approach this type of thing.

Any ideas how to implement that? Any help will be much appreciated!